# Unhedged factor models in trading

Tags: hedging, factor-models, factor-investing

Suppose I have a factor model that takes in unemployment and GDP as $X_1, X_2$ respectively in estimating the fair price of asset $Y$. Say I observe that the market price of $Y$ has deviated significantly from the estimate from my model.

My intuition says this signal cannot be used as a trading signal because while price of $Y$ is in dislocation, two of the factors are non-tradable. This means that market price of $Y$ could converge to fair price by way of movement in $X_1, X_2$ and it doesn't carry definitive information on the price direction of $Y$.

Is my interpretation correct or am I missing something? How are factor models actually used in practice?

Update: GDP and unemployment may have been a bad example, as they change infrequently. For the sake of argument, assume GDP and unemployment updates on second-to-second basis.

Comment: You need empirical data, then you can check if the signal today predicts the change in Y in the next period, if it predicts change in X1 X2, or if it doesn't predict anything. (For example do a regression of future $\Delta Y$ on the current signal, is it statistically significant?).

Comment: But in general you are right: just because there is a relationship between contemporanous Y X1 X2 does not mean it will be useful for prediction (i.e. across time periods).